# Combinatorics, marks to students

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

please am I right in my solutions for these problems ?

There was a test in a school, but teacher lost all the completed tests. He has to give some points to studens.

a)How many possibilities are there, if he wants to give some points from set {0,1,2,3,4} to all 20 students ? Studets are uniqe (recognizable by name).

b)How many possibilities are there to give some points to students, if teacher has to give each number from set {0,1,2,3,4} at least once ?

c)How many possibilities are there to give points to students, if teacher has forgot names of students and he is only deciding, how many times he give point 0, how many times he give point 1, how many times he give point 2...etc.

---

a) 5^20 ?

b) (C = Combination number)  C(20,5) (give 5 students marks) * 5!(all permutations of marks for theese 5 students) * C(19,15) (possibilities to give other marks to students) = C(20,5)*5!*(19,15) ?

c) n=5(points),k=20(students)(C = Combination number) C(5-1+20,20) = C(24,20) ?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for a.  For b, subtract from a the number of ways to give any set of only four marks.  You have now subtracted the ways with only three marks twice, so add them back in.  Think inclusion-exclusion.  c is fine.

Comment: If I see it correctly, is it 5^20 - 4^20 + 3^20 - 2^20 + 1^20 ?

Comment: Or do I have to add combination numbers in front of each part of equasion, to choose which grade is the teacher using ? Like this  C(5,5)5^20 - C(5,4)4^20 + C(5,3)3^20 - C(5,2)2^20 + C(5,1)1^20

Comment: Yes, you need the combination numbers as in your second comment.